# Access structure in Swift array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Can I access a struct inside of an array that is defined in the application delegate from a ViewController?

I get the error:
'Any' does not have a member named 'title' in XCode 6.2

What is the syntax for accessing a structure inside of the array?

```
//AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

struct TodoItem {
    var title: String
}

var todoItem = TodoItem(
    title: "Get Milk")

var myArray: [Any] = []
```

And then in the ViewController

```
//
//  ViewController.swift


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    //here I'm adding the struct to the array
    let myTodoItem = delegate.myArray.append(delegate.todoItem)

    //how do I access the items in the struct?
    println(delegate.myArray[0].title)
```

Answer (score 3):

### You can access structures in array same as you would classes.

**Your issue** is that you explicitly tell that the array contains `Any` Objects. Type the array to be of type `MyStruct` and it works fine:

```
var myArray: [MyStructure] = [];
```

alternatively, if you can't modify the array declaration, cast:

```
myValueIWannaRead = (myArray[0] as MyStruct).myValueIWannaRead
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the array to store the type you desire :

```
var myArray: [TodoItem] = [];
```

Then you can access the instances properly.

The `Any` type denotes an object of an unknown type (class/primitive type ) and during compilation time there is no way to know which type the instance accessed will be of.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift be always as specific as possible.

If the array contains only items of type `TodoItem`, declare it respectively.

```
var myArray: [TodoItem] = []
```

`Any` is a kind of placeholder, the compiler has no idea what dynamic type it is.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to add the `struct TodoItem` to AppDelegate? in my point of view, it would be better to create it in the same file that you have your view controller or - even better - create a new Swift file named TodoItem.swift holding the struct.

Then after you have moved your struct to a new file or inside your View Controller file, but outside your ViewController class. You can just call:

```
let myTodoItem = TodoItem(title: "Get Milk") // declaring TodoItem
var myTodoItemArray : [TodoItem] = [] // declaring TodoItem array
myTodoItemArray.append(myTodoItem) // Appending to the array

// then you can set it by calling the array only member
let todoItem = myTodoItemArray[0] as! TodoItem
let title = todoItem.title

// Or you can just call the toDo Item itself
let title = myTodoItem.title
```

If you want to comunicate this data between two different classes, I would suggest use **Delegation** by creating a protocol or **Notifications** with NSNotifications.

I hopw this helps, happy coding.

EDIT: Fixed some minor error in the code

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1:** Your struct is defined under AppDelegate class so, you will have to parse it like this;

```
    //** Swift 1.2, xCode 6.3.1**//
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    //here I'm adding the struct to the array
    delegate.myArray.append(delegate.todoItem)

    //how do I access the items in the struct?
    println((delegate.myArray[0] as! AppDelegate.TodoItem).title)
```

**Solution2:** Change the data type of your array Any to TodoItem

```
var myArray: [TodoItem] = []
```

and then, it would work;

```
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    //here I'm adding the struct to the array
    delegate.myArray.append(delegate.todoItem)

    //how do I access the items in the struct?
    println(delegate.myArray[0].title)
```